# Has there been a change to the custom PMD ruleset file format in recent years - and if so, how do I migrate?

Tags: pmd

I have a rule file that [fails to be recognized](https://github.com/amitdev/PMD-Intellij/issues/10) by the PMD-IntelliJ plugin.

The plugin's author suggested I might be using an outdated custom ruleset (file) format version.

That's quite possible, the ruleset file is ages old, and so far was only used with Eclipse and its PMD plugin.

I am currently a bit short of time, so I was hoping someone could

- let me know if there has been a format change to the custom PMD ruleset file formats in the last couple of years.
- have a look at an excerpt from our rules file (posted below) and tell me what they think the file format version we use is; and
- point me to an explanation of how to migrate to the most recent version.

I don't know anything about PMD so far, and just want to get this to work in IntelliJ. Medium-term, I plan on learning about it, but right now, I'm basically hoping for a quick fix... :)

P.S.: This is a [cross-post](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188193/thread/ee2cf3d7/#261b) from the PMD forums...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="exampleruleset">
<description>foo bar</description>
<rule name="DoubleCheckedLocking"
          message="Double checked locking is not thread safe."
          class="net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.DoubleCheckedLocking"
          externalInfoUrl="http://example.com/wiki/PMDRuleDoubleCheckedLocking">
  <priority>1</priority>
</rule>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a rule from PMD 4.x. With the switch to PMD 5 there have been a lot of incompatible [changes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/5.0.0/) like restructuring the packages.

It looks like, you just want to execute one rule, which is DoubleCheckedLocking. I agree with [this suggestion](https://github.com/amitdev/PMD-Intellij/issues/10) to just reference the rule, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
        xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>This ruleset checks my code for bad stuff</description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/DoubleCheckedLocking"/>
</ruleset>
```

The default priority of this rule is already "1", so there is no need to override the priority.
See also [How to make a new rule set](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/howtomakearuleset.html) and the [available rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/rules/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @adangel. Actually, the above is only a small excerpt, to show the rule format. there are a lot more rules defines in that file, all of them using XPath. Which is why an "upgrade tutorial" would be so handy... ;-)